# @use is ignored in sass compilation

Tags: webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am using Laravel-mix to compile my assets with webpack.

When calling `npm run dev` I get this warning:

```
  (Emitted value instead of an instance of Error)   resolve-url-loader cannot operate: CSS error
  /home/adam/www/homestead/memberportal/resources/assets/css/listing/funny.scss:2:264: missing '{'
  at error (/home/adam/www/homestead/memberportal/node_modules/css/lib/parse/index.js:62:15)

 @ ./resources/assets/css/listing/funny.scss 4:14-280
 @ multi ./node_modules/laravel-mix/src/builder/mock-entry.js ./resources/assets/css/listing/funny.scss
```

It seems that sass comping is not working.

This is my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.sass('resources/assets/css/listing/funny.scss', 'public/css/');
```

This is the content of `funny.scss`:

```
@use 'xy';
```

this is the content of `_xy.scss`:

```
h1{
  color: red;
}
```

This is the outcome of the compiled `funny.css`

```
@use "xy";
```

Why is sasss compiling not working here?

Comment: I suggest that you comment out the files one by one starting from `custom.scss`, and work from there.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman yes I did that, and I am now at a  point where it seems that `sass` compiling is not working. I will reduce it to a minimal example.

Comment: @Ma'mounothman I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow my `package.json` was missing the dependency. Must have lost it during branching somehow. Adding `sass`, `sass-loader` and `resolve-url-loader` fixed the problem for me:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "babel-plugin-component": "^1.1.1",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
        "fibers": "^4.0.2",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "laravel-mix-purgecss": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "purify-css": "^1.2.5",
        "purifycss-webpack": "^0.7.0",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.26.3",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
        "vuetifyjs-mix-extension": "0.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "buefy": "^0.8.17",
        "modal-video": "^2.4.2"
    }
}
```